# Counting number of time the articles "a","an" are being used in a text file

Tags: java, counting

I'm trying to make a program that count the number of words, lines, sentences, and also the number of articles 'a', 'and','the'.
So far I got the words, lines, sentences. But I have no idea who I am going to count the articles. How can a program make the difference between 'a' and 'and'.

This my code so far.

```
 public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException        
    {       
FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\nlstudent\\Downloads\\text.txt");
Scanner sfile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\nlstudent\\Downloads\\text.txt"));

  int ch,sentence=0,words = 0,chars = 0,lines = 0; 

  while((ch=file.read())!=-1)
  {
   if(ch=='?'||ch=='!'|| ch=='.')
    sentence++;
  }

    while(sfile.hasNextLine())  {
        lines++;
    String line = sfile.nextLine();
        chars += line.length();
        words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
    }


System.out.println("Number of words: " + words);
System.out.println("Number of sentence: " + sentence);
System.out.println("Number of lines: " + lines);
System.out.println("Number of characters: " + chars);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokenizer will split each line into tokens. You can evaluate each token (a whole word) to see if it matches a string you expect. Here is an example to count a, and, the.

```
int a = 0, and = 0, the = 0, forCount = 0;

while (sfile.hasNextLine()) {
    lines++;
    String line = sfile.nextLine();
    chars += line.length();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ,");
    words += tokenizer.countTokens();

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String element = (String) tokenizer.nextElement();

        if ("a".equals(element)) {
            a++;
        } else if ("and".equals(element)) {
            and++;
        } else if ("for".equals(element)) {
            forCount++;
        } else if ("the".equals(element)) {
            the++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use this technique for the article 'for', since it's a reserved word?

Comment: Use an integer variable with a different name than `for`. Perhaps `forCount`. Then add an else if clause to count occurrences of the word for. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

> How can a program make the difference between 'a' and 'and'.

You can use regex for this:

```
        String input = "A and Andy then the are a";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b((a)|(an)|(and)|(the))\\b").matcher(input);
        int count = 0;
        while(m.find()){
            count++;
        }
        //count == 4
```

'\b' is a *word boundary*, '|' is *OR*, '(?i)' — *ignore case* flag. All list of patterns you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and probably you should learn about regex.